# Save file to Document directory in liferay 6.1 using API

Tags: file, upload, liferay, liferay-6

I need to save a uploaded file in sub directory of Document & Media folder in liferay from web-form portlet.
I have extended the web Form portlet to do so, but file is getting uploaded successfully in database & not in Document & Media folder.
I tried following code to upload the file in document directory but no success  please help .

```java
ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) actionRequest.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);

String title = file.getName();

DLFolder dlFolder = DLFolderLocalServiceUtil.getFolder(themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId(), 0, "Test");

ServiceContext serviceContext = ServiceContextFactory.getInstance(DLFileEntry.class.getName(),actionRequest);

Map<String, Fields> fieldsMap = new HashMap<String, Fields>();

long fileEntryTypeId = DLFileEntryTypeConstants.FILE_ENTRY_TYPE_ID_BASIC_DOCUMENT;

FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

DLFileEntry dlFileEntry = DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.addFileEntry(themeDisplay.getUserId(), 10153, dlFolder.getRepositoryId(), 
                            dlFolder.getRepositoryId(), title, file.getContentType(), title, "fileDesc", "sss",
                            fileEntryTypeId, fieldsMap, file, inputStream, file.length(), serviceContext);

inputStream.close();

DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.updateFileEntry(themeDisplay.getUserId(), dlFileEntry.getFileEntryId(), title, file.getContentType(),
        title, "fileDesc", "comment", true, dlFileEntry.getFileEntryTypeId(), fieldsMap, file, null, file.length(), serviceContext);
```

Comment: This does not even compile - duplicate use of `file`, I couldn't find this interface of `DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil` in http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs-all/com/liferay/portlet/documentlibrary/service/DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.html#addFileEntry(long,%20long,%20long,%20long,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20long,%20java.util.Map,%20java.io.File,%20java.io.InputStream,%20long,%20com.liferay.portal.service.ServiceContext). Please check

Comment: Hi Olaf Thanks for reply.I am very new in liferay.
I have edited my query can you please take a look at it once.. 
Thanks

Comment: What datatype is `file` here? I have similar problems but at least for `java.io.File` I don't have a method called `getContentType()`.

Comment: Also, what does the groupId 10153 refer to? I have no idea what to input there.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code snippet

```
ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) actionRequest.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
ServiceContext serviceContext = ServiceContextFactory.getInstance(actionRequest);

File file = uploadRequest.getFile("file");
String contentType = MimeTypesUtil.getContentType(file);

InputStream inputStream  = new FileInputStream(file);

Folder folderName = DLAppLocalServiceUtil.getFolder(parentRepositoryId, 
                                                    parentFolderId, 
                                                    "Folder Name");
long folderId = folderName.getFolderId();
long repositoryId = folderName.getRepositoryId();

FileEntry fileEntry = DLAppLocalServiceUtil.addFileEntry(themeDisplay.getUserId(), 
                                                         repositoryId, 
                                                         folderId, 
                                                         file.getName(), 
                                                         contentType, 
                                                         "File Name", 
                                                         "description", 
                                                         "changeLog", 
                                                         inputStream, 
                                                         file.length(), 
                                                         serviceContext);
```

Comment: What is `parentRepositoryId` and `parentFolderId` there? I want to upload a file as a user, if there is a home folder for users or something like that that would be fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but I had similar issue today. I used `DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil`, and I had to call both `addFileEntry()` and `updateFileEntry()` in order to correctly create the asset.

See [Liferay DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.addFileEntry does not create AssetEntry record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20283885/liferay-dlfileentrylocalserviceutil-addfileentry-does-not-create-assetentry-reco)