# Invalid property on line changeLog in liferay programatic uploading into document and library

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, portal

06, i want to upload the files into document and library, i have searched and written the code like this, i have got error invalid property change log. can any one correct my code? and i have another doubt repository id and comapny id are same? and in portlet it showing You have entered invalid data. Please try again.

```
public void uploadBook(ActionRequest actionRequest,
                             ActionResponse actionRresponse) throws PortletException,
                             IOException, com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.PortalException, com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.SystemException {
              UploadPortletRequest uploadRequest = PortalUtil.getUploadPortletRequest(actionRequest);
              String submissionFileName = uploadRequest.getFileName("file");//uploaded filename
              ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) actionRequest.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
                ServiceContext serviceContext = ServiceContextFactory.getInstance(actionRequest);

                File file = uploadRequest.getFile("file");
                String contentType = MimeTypesUtil.getContentType(file);

                InputStream inputStream  = new FileInputStream(file);

                String folderName="library";
                long folderId = 11502;
                long repositoryId =10132;

                //java.io.File file = ( java.io.File)uploadRequest.getFile("file");
               // InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);

                DLFileEntry fileEntry = DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.addFileEntry(themeDisplay.getUserId(), 
                                                                                repositoryId, 
                                                                                folderId, 
                                                                                file.getName(), 
                                                                                contentType, 
                                                                                submissionFileName, 
                                                                                "no description", 
                                                                                "changeLog", 
                                                                                inputStream, 
                                                                                file.length(),
                                                                                serviceContext);

        //addFileEntry(long userId, long groupId, long folderId, String name, String title, String description, String changeLog, String extraSettings, byte[] bytes, ServiceContext serviceContext)
         String successMessage ="File Uploaded Successfully";
         SessionMessages.add(actionRequest, "request_rocessed",successMessage);
    }
```

Comment: refer this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17919271/save-file-to-document-directory-in-liferay-6-1-using-api/17924745#17924745

Answer (score 0):

You can refer EditFileEntryAction.java method updateFileEntry(..) for what parameter are getting passed.

repositoryId by default is groupId where you are adding your document (i.e. site or organization).

FolderId has to be existing folder Id of that group (site or org)

changeLog pass it as blank ""

Paste the complete stacktrace / logs from Tomcat