# Liferay DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.addFileEntry does not create AssetEntry record

Tags: java, liferay, portlet

I have a custom portlet which provides a form where the user can upload files. The uploaded file should be stored in the Documents and Media Portlet. I am creating the file entry using `DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.addFileEntry`. The file is succesfully uploaded and the record in `DLFileEntry` table is created, but in the `AssetEntry` table no new record is created. I suppose Liferay should create it automatically, am I wrong?
Where could be the error?

This is my code:

```
DLFileEntry dlFileEntry = DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.addFileEntry(user.getUserId(),
    groupId,
    groupId, //repositoryId,
        folder.getFolderId(),
    fName,
    mimeType,
    title,
    "", //description
    "", //changeLog,
    0,  //fileEntryTypeId
    null,   //fieldsMaps
    file,
    null,   //inputstream
    file.length(),
    serviceContext);
```

I get the form data from the `UploadPortletRequest` object ( `UploadPortletRequest uploadRequest = PortalUtil.getUploadPortletRequest(actionRequest);` )

I have the following `ServiceContext`:

```
ServiceContext serviceContext = new ServiceContext();
long[] assetCategoryIds = new long[assetCategoryIdsList.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < assetCategoryIdsList.size(); i++) {
    assetCategoryIds[i] = assetCategoryIdsList.get(i);
}
serviceContext.setAssetCategoryIds(assetCategoryIds);
serviceContext.setScopeGroupId(groupId);
if(!tagNames.equals("")) {
    serviceContext.setAssetTagNames(tagNames.split(","));
}
```

Comment: Which Liferay version you are using?

Comment: I am using Liferay 6.1.20 EE version

Answer (score 2):

It's not enough calling only `DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.addFileEntry`

After `addFileEntry` call `DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.updateStatus(userId, fileVersionId, WorkflowConstants.STATUS_APPROVED, emptyMap, serviceContext);`

With this method the `AssetEntry` is created and published

Comment: It did not work, but I tried also calling `DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.updateFileEntry()`, and it solved the problem. But can anyone explain, why need I two function calls to create one single file??? And why is it not properly documented??? I have spent days for finding a solution... It is ridiculous...

Comment: Remember Liferay has workflow, it's necessary to approve the content you have created

Comment: @ttamas: By "*also*", do you mean it works when calling the 3 methods addFileEntry+updateStatus+updateFileEntry, or only addFileEntry+updateFileEntry ?

Comment: In Liferay 6.2, you can also use `DLAppLocalServiceUtil.addFileEntry()`. Approved status can be set like this: `serviceContext.setWorkflowAction(WorkflowConstants.ACTION_PUBLISH)`, without calling updateStatus separately.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this property in your portal -

`#asset.renderer.enabled.com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.asset.DLFileEntryAssetRendererFactory=`

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'com.liferay.document.library.kernel.service.DLAppServiceUtil' this service, and may be your problem will solved.