# Liferay throw me a NoSuchEntryException after DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.addFileEntry

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, liferay, liferay-6

I'm trying to add images programmatically to liferay Documents Library.
I'm using liferay portal 6.1.30 ee.

Here is my code:

```
    protected void addDocument(long userId, Group group, InputStream inputStream, DLFolder dlFolder, String name) throws IOException {
    long fileEntryTypeId;
    try {
        fileEntryTypeId = DLFileEntryTypeLocalServiceUtil.getDefaultFileEntryTypeId(dlFolder.getFolderId());
    } catch (NestableException e) {
        if(LOGGER.isWarningEnabled())LOGGER.warn("unable to get fileEntryType ",e);
        return;
    }

    ServiceContext serviceContext = new ServiceContext();
    serviceContext.setCompanyId(group.getCompanyId());
    serviceContext.setScopeGroupId(group.getGroupId());
    serviceContext.setAssetEntryVisible(true);

    try {
        DLFileEntry fileEntry = DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.addFileEntry(userId, group.getGroupId(), dlFolder.getRepositoryId(),
                dlFolder.getFolderId(), name, MimeTypesUtil.getContentType(name), name,
                StringPool.BLANK, StringPool.BLANK, fileEntryTypeId, null, null,
                inputStream, inputStream.available(), new ServiceContext());


        //fileEntry = DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.updateDLFileEntry(fileEntry);
        //fileEntry = DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.updateFileEntry(fileEntry.getUserId(),fileEntry.getFileEntryTypeId(),name,MimeTypesUtil.getContentType(name),name,StringPool.BLANK,StringPool.BLANK,false, fileEntryTypeId, new HashMap<String, Fields>(), null, fileEntry.getContentStream(), fileEntry.getSize(),serviceContext);
        //fileEntry = DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.updateStatus(fileEntry.getUserId(), fileEntry.getFileVersion().getFileVersionId(), WorkflowConstants.STATUS_APPROVED, new HashMap<String, Serializable>(), serviceContext);

        if(LOGGER.isTraceEnabled()) LOGGER.trace("file "+name+" added");
    } catch (NestableException e) {
        if(LOGGER.isWarningEnabled())LOGGER.warn("error adding file "+name+" ",e);
    }
}
```

I try using DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.addFileEntry but it doesn't create my documents properly, as I red in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20283885/liferay-dlfileentrylocalserviceutil-addfileentry-does-not-create-assetentry-reco) no assetEntry record is created.

So I tried DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.updateStatus (commented here) but i got this error, still no assetEntry:

> com.liferay.portlet.asset.NoSuchEntryException: No AssetEntry exists
>   with the key {classNameId=10076, classPK=42954} 
> at
>   com.liferay.portlet.asset.service.persistence.AssetEntryPersistenceImpl.findByC_C(AssetEntryPersistenceImpl.java:2933)
>   
>         at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1937.invoke(Unknown
>   Source) 
>         at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) 
>   at
>   com.liferay.portal.security.lang.DoPrivilegedHandler.doInvoke(DoPrivilegedHandler.java:88)
>   
>         at
>   com.liferay.portal.security.lang.DoPrivilegedHandler.invoke(DoPrivilegedHandler.java:56)
>   
>         at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy689.findByC_C(Unknown Source)
>   
>         at
>   com.liferay.portlet.asset.service.impl.AssetEntryLocalServiceImpl.updateVisible(AssetEntryLocalServiceImpl.java:866)
>   
>         at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1936.invoke(Unknown
>   Source) 
>         at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) 
>   at
>   com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:117)
>   
>         at
>   com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.DefaultTransactionExecutor.execute(DefaultTransactionExecutor.java:62)
>   
>         at
>   com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:52)
>   
>         at
>   com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:113)
>   
>         at
>   com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
>   
>         at
>   com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:113)
>   
>         at
>   com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
>   
>         at
>   com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:113)
>   
>         at
>   com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
>   
>         at
>   com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:113)
>   
>         at
>   com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
>   
>         at
>   com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:113)
>   
>         at
>   com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:218)
>   
>         at
>   com.liferay.portal.security.pacl.PACLInvocationHandler.doInvoke(PACLInvocationHandler.java:62)
>   
>         at
>   com.liferay.portal.security.pacl.PACLInvocationHandler.invoke(PACLInvocationHandler.java:51)
>   
>         at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy394.updateVisible(Unknown Source)
>   
>         at
>   com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.impl.DLAppHelperLocalServiceImpl.updateStatus(DLAppHelperLocalServiceImpl.java:584)
>   
>         at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1935.invoke(Unknown
>   Source) 
>         at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) 
>   at
>   com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:117)
>   
>         at
>   com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.DefaultTransactionExecutor.execute(DefaultTransactionExecutor.java:62)
>   
>         at
>   com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:52)
>   
>         at
>   com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:113)
>   
>         at
>   com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
>   
>         at
>   com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:113)
>   
>         at
>   com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
>   
>         at
>   com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:113)
>   
>         at
>   com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
>   
>         at
>   com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:113)
>   
>         at
>   com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
>   
>         at
>   com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:113)
>   
>         at
>   com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:218)
>   
>         at
>   com.liferay.portal.security.pacl.PACLInvocationHandler.doInvoke(PACLInvocationHandler.java:62)
>   
>         at
>   com.liferay.portal.security.pacl.PACLInvocationHandler.invoke(PACLInvocationHandler.java:51)
>   
>         at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy466.updateStatus(Unknown Source)
>   
>         at
>   com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.impl.DLFileEntryLocalServiceImpl.updateStatus(DLFileEntryLocalServiceImpl.java:1298)
>   
>         at
>   com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.DLFileEntryLocalServiceWrapper.updateStatus(DLFileEntryLocalServiceWrapper.java:624)
>   
>         at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1933.invoke(Unknown
>   Source) 
>         at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) 
>   at
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:67)
>   
>         at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy782.updateStatus(Unknown Source)
>   
>         at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1933.invoke(Unknown
>   Source) 
>         at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) 
>   at
>   com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:117)
>   
>         at
>   com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.DefaultTransactionExecutor.execute(DefaultTransactionExecutor.java:62)
>   
>         at
>   com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:52)
>   
>         at
>   com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:113)
>   
>         at
>   com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
>   
>         at
>   com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:113)
>   
>         at
>   com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
>   
>         at
>   com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:113)
>   
>         at
>   com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
>   
>         at
>   com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:113)
>   
>         at
>   com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
>   
>         at
>   com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:113)
>   
>         at
>   com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:218)
>   
>         at
>   com.liferay.portal.security.pacl.PACLInvocationHandler.doInvoke(PACLInvocationHandler.java:62)
>   
>         at
>   com.liferay.portal.security.pacl.PACLInvocationHandler.invoke(PACLInvocationHandler.java:51)
>   
>         at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy468.updateStatus(Unknown Source)
>   
>         at
>   com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.updateStatus(DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.java:626)
>   
>         at xxx.addDocument()

and i tried calling methods DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.updateDLFileEntry or updateFileEntry
 but it make no difference

edit:

I found a solution using this code after addFileEntry:

```
    fileEntry = DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.updateFileEntry(userId, fileEntry.getFileEntryId(),name, MimeTypesUtil.getContentType(name), name,"", "", true, fileEntryTypeId, null, null, null, 0, serviceContext);
    Map<String, Serializable> workflowContext = new HashMap<String, Serializable>();
    workflowContext.put("event",DLSyncConstants.EVENT_UPDATE);
    fileEntry = DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.updateStatus(fileEntry.getUserId(), fileEntry.getFileVersion().getFileVersionId(), WorkflowConstants.STATUS_APPROVED, workflowContext, serviceContext);
```

Comment: Any updates to this issue? Did the answer help you? If it did, you can accept it as the answer or if you fixed this on your own, you might want to add your own solution as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could try with the methods in DLFileAppLocalServiceUtil. They generate file's metadata and others required fields like file version.

HTH.